# Aspose.Cells: initialize empty workbook, workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells has no cells in it

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

Here's my code:

```
var workbook = new Workbook();
var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

var row = 1;
var column = 1;
sheet.Cells.GetCell(row, column).Value = "Date";
```

This causes a null reference error because GetCell() returned null. Is this normal behavior? How can I properly initialize a workbook with a single blank worksheet, such that sheet.Cells.GetCell(1, 1) will not be null?

Comment: are you sure you don't need to add a new worksheet? something like workbook.Worksheets.Add();

Comment: I've tried that route as well. Still doesn't work. The worksheet in the code above is not null-- the workbook initializes with one sheet.

Comment: if I remember, you also have sheet.Cells[row, column].PutValue("Date");

Answer (score 2):

**GetCell()** method returns null when the cell has not been created earlier. However, **Worksheet.Cells[r, c]** will always return cell object because it returns the cell object if it already exists, otherwise it first creates it and then returns the cell object. It means, Worksheet.Cells[r, c] will never return null.

Please execute the following code at your end. The code explains, first time, GetCell() methods return null but second time, it returns cell object because it has already been created by Worksheet.Cells[r, c].

Please read the comments for your more help.

**C#**

```
//Create empty workbook.
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//This will return null because the cell is not initialized before.
Cell c = ws.Cells.GetCell(2, 5);

//This will automatically create cell object, so it will never return null.
c = ws.Cells[2, 5];

//Now execute the previous statement, this time, GetCell() will also return cell object
//because it has been created by ws.Cells[2, 5]
c = null;
c = ws.Cells.GetCell(2, 5);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose